# Generate discord server invite using discord server ID using PHP

Tags: php, discord

I need to generate a discord server invite link using a discord server ID in PHP.
I am making a thing on my website where users can save their discord server ID and a link to that discord server will be showed on their profile.
The purpose of this is so that there will always be a working invite link for users viewing their profile.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: You don't. Discord generates them, and only if the server admins have configured their settings to allow users _of that server_ to generate them. The best you can do is list the general server URL and people can try to join from that if public signups are enabled.

Comment: I don't think it's impossible, I've seen websites have a similar feature where you give them the ID and they embed an invite.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would instead allow the user to simply supply the invite URL. From this, you can fetch the invite URL to see if it's valid, which will also contain the guild id (if it's not a group direct message invite).

If that is not possible, then the answer is simply "Not possible." If users may enter a Discord server id, there's no way to validate if it's actually a server id. Assuming you check to see if it's discoverable, you still can't get an invite from that.

Comment: I don't think it's impossible, I've seen websites have a similar feature where you give them the ID and they embed an invite.